# Gnome freeze when click on "parameters"

Tags: arch-linux, gnome, startx

I just installed archlinux (4.16.13-2-ARCH). After some configurations concerning the wifi and the users, I decided to install a GUI: GNOME.

I started by installing `xorg-xinit, xorg-server and xorg-apps.` I created a `.xinitrc` file in my `~/` by copying it from `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc`. I modified the `.xinitrc` file by commenting the lines from `tvm` to the end (as indicated in the official Archlinux documentation: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit). And at the end of this file, I added this: `exec gnome-session`.

For now, I do not want to use GDM because I want to have my terminal from the beginning.

So after modifying this file and after login by tty, I launched the `startx` command.

GNOME launches correctly (I believe it) after a time that I find long (1 minutes, is this normal with an SSD?). But when I click on "settings" or on the application "cheese" for example, the mouse cursor becomes a loading wheel and ... All Freeze! Forced to turn off the PC by the button ...

I admit to being lost, having little knowledge around Linux ...
I read a lot of messages on forums but nothing seems to stick to my problem.
If anyone has an idea of ​​where to look or what's going on, I'm interested!

Comment: Can you still kill the X server with Ctrl+Alt+Backspace to avoid the hard reboot at least? Can you switch to one of the TTYs?

Comment: I find solution: my Graphic Driver wasn't installed. Work better with NVIDIA driver and Bumblebee.